# Integral inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

I have read that the following is an inner product for two real continuous functions on the interval $a \leq t \leq b$ :

$\langle a,b\rangle = \int^{b}_{a}f(t)g(t)dt$

However, one of the requirements of an inner product is that it is always $\geq0$. How is this always the case with the above? Say I took $f(t)=-1$ and $g(t)=1$, both are continuous on the interval $-1\leq t \leq 0$ yet clearly the integral would be negative. Is there some extra condition I am missing? (Perhaps I have to consider the *whole* range it is continuous over, in which case the integral would be $0$ as $t$ would extend from $-\infty$ to $\infty$).

Comment: It's actually $\langle f,g\rangle$ not $\langle a,b\rangle$ ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property you are referring to, says that $\langle f,f\rangle\geq0$ for all continuous $f$ and **not** $\langle f,g\rangle\geq0$ for all continuous $f,g$.

See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Definition).

Comment: Ah that makes perfect sense now. Thank you.